# How much memory does it waste to use object literals over classes?

Tags: javascript, performance, jit

In modern JavaScript written in a functional-ish stlye, it is common to use a lot of object literals, so something like:

```js
function makeCow() {
  return {
    moo() { console.log("moo") }
  }
}

let emma = makeCow();
let britt = makeCow();
```

Instead of the more "classical":

```js
class Cow
  moo() { console.log("moo") }
}

let emma = new Cow();
let britt = new Cow();
```

I always have a gut feeling that the former style is wasteful in terms of memory. The class based code above boils down to a single allocation with `Cow.prototype` as the prototype of the created object. The object literal based code however needs to allocate once for every single function that the object literal has. It will also need to allocate much bigger objects to hold all of the functions.

There are two reasons that this might be fine anyway:

1. JITs are probably very good at optimizing this stuff. Mostly they should be able to recognize that I'm building a lot of similar objects and be able to cache a lot of things.
2. Performance doesn't matter. YOLO.

So should I be worried about this at all? Does it make a difference whether I'm building an application or writing library code which will be used in high performance applications?

N.B. that I'm aware that I could be writing the code in a fully functional style where `moo` is a free function, but in this case I *do* want property access, and so using a functional style would not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: If in doubt, measure it. Notice that in your example with only two instances, the `class` setup itself will probably take more memory - it will become relevant only once you have thousands of instances.

Comment: You could still have `makeCow` as a constructor function, call it with `new` and attach `moo` to the prototype and still avoid `class`. Is there a reason you would favor this approach with such rudimentary factory method that allocates fresh copy of `moo` in each instance over a proper constructor function and methods in the prototype?

Comment: @Bergi I'm talking about this case if there are thousands or even millions of the given objects, in the case where there are only three it obviously doesn't matter.

Comment: @WiktorZychla there are a couple of reasons that people seem to prefer this approach, I myself am not necessarily an advocate, but I've definitely seen a lot of code written this way. One reason is that it meshes better with TypeScript. While classes and object literals work fine with TypeScript, adding properties to `prototype` does not. Another reason people seem to prefer this is a general aversion towards classes, which I don't really understand, but it's definitely a thing. A third reason is that all functions on the object literal are bound, which can be nice.

Comment: You can use a "free function" also with properties (except if you want to access local variables in `makeCow`).

Comment: _"it is common to use a lot of object literals"_... Frankly, I've _never_ seen it done this way...

That said, the performance difference will be so negligible... Don't bother :D

Comment: @jnicklas Yes, in those cases I'd use a `class`. I guess it's just common to use object literals in code as there are more cases with less instances.

Comment: @jnicklas: thanks, I know the story behind and I was specifically interested in your motivation (if any).